# Dismissing WEPPopover from its subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am presenting a `WEPPopoverController` in my iPhone Application. In that WEPPopoverController, I have added a `UITableViewController`. This popover I am using for the purpose of search.

Now when I open this Popover, the screen looks something like this:

[image]

Now, I want to close dismiss this Popover from the `UITableViewController's` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`,

How to do this?

Code:

```
self.searchTableViewController = [[SearchTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];    // UITableViewController
self.seachPopoverController = [[[WEPPopoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.searchTableViewController] autorelease];   // WepPopoverController

self.seachPopoverController.delegate = self;
[self.seachPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[searchB frame] inView:topPanelV permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you post your code how do you present WEPopoverController ?

Comment: Here is the code which I have use for presenting WepPopoverController and putting a UITableViewController inside it.

Comment: Is your controller delegate for UITableViewController, I mean didSelectRowAtIndex method is in your controller where you present this ?

Comment: No it is inside the UITableViewController class which I am adding to the Popover.

Comment: Check my answer. That will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add 1 variable in SearchTableViewController as parent like

```
id parent;
```

Create property for this as

```
@property (nonatomic,assign)id parent;
```

Synthesize it

```
@synthesize parent;
```

Now

when you create `self.searchTableViewController`

assign its parent as

```
self.searchTableViewController.parent = self;
```

Now in didSelectRowAtIndex

```
[parent dismisMyPopoverMethod];


-(void)dismisMyPopoverMethod
{
[self.seachPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
self.seachPopoverController = nil;         
}
```

And thats it. Your are done.

Comment: Ohh when Posted comment you already accepted. Thax once again.

Comment: Hey need one more help, can you suggest, when the table is empty then it won't detect didSelectRowAtIndexPath, at that time from where should I call [parent dismisMyPopoverMethod]; ?

Comment: In that case you can do like when table is empty don't present popover i.e. when you search and result is empty you must be having condition in your same view controller and just don't present it.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way: make your view controller a delegate of table view controller for only one method - dismissPopover (for other methods the delegate must be table view controller). So your table view controller will have two delegates. Implement this method in your delegate (view controller). But call it from table view controller. In more details step by step:

Declare a property of your popover in a view controller, where you show this popover.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
```

Create a new protocol (let's name it TableInPopoverDelegate), that has this method:

```
- (void) dismissPopover;
```

Add this method to the implementation file of your view controller and add this:

```
- (void) dismissPopover {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Add a header file of protocol and add a delegate property to your table view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <TableInPopoverDelegate> popoverDelegate;
```

Make your view controller a delegate of your table view controller before adding it:

```
tableViewController.popoverDelegate = self; // Here self is your view controller
```

Call dismissPopover on the delegate when user selects a row.

```
[popoverDelegate dismissPopover];
```

Comment: No its not dismissing as it has been presented from a different view controller. And the table from which you are asking to dismiss the popover, is the subview of the popover

Comment: Why are you giving me the code to present it, Its already been presented, I want code to dismiss it from the popover's subview.